# Jmeter BeanShell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Am new to JMeter. I have extracted my required values from response data using regular expression extractor. Now I need to use these etracted values to select a particular data from the list.

I have few data listed. In these data, few have edit enabled and few data's edit are disabled. I have to instruct JMeter to select data that have edit enabled. there are 3 conditions to have edit enabled which is:

```
is_final = 1 
is_locked = 0 
status_id = 1
```

I have extracted these values from response data. But I donot know how to use BeanShell to instruct JMeter to select data that have edit enabled. Please help me on this.

Comment: where is the list? what kind of list? what kind of data do you want jmeter to select?

Answer (score 1):

the syntax of the Beanshell script is quite similar to Java. Say, you have a list of elements: `ArrayList<element> list` and each `element` has fields:`is_final`,`is_locked`,`status_id`, so you can write a loop to go through all the elemnts in the list like

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).is_final == 1 && list.get(i).is_locked == 0 && list.get(i).status_id == 1){
           return list.get(i);
        }
```

hope this is helpful to you!
 [about jmeter's introduction on beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and beanshell's [offifical wiki](http://www.beanshell.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the single values out of Extracted array. First you need to understand these variables are stored as for eg:MYREF_g0,MYREF_g1,MYREF_g2

So if you wanted to extract say status_id in your case which is stored at 3rd array position in ReferenceName say Abc. then refrence variable name should be${Abc_g2}.

Same applies for other values like ${Abc_g0},${Abc_g1}.

Hope this helps.!